# Hibernate Search and Lucene: cannot determine sort type

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate - Lucene Search.

I have the following Runtime Exception while sorting when no data available in index file/table.

This is my code:

..........
..........
query.setFirstResult(startIndex);
                query.setMaxResults(displayCount);

```
                 Sort sort = null;
            SortField sortField = new SortField**("vendorName",!true);
            sort = new Sort(sortField);
            query.setSort(sort);

            objList = query.setProjection(searchFields).setResultTransformer(objSavantAliasToBeanResultTransformer).list();
```

........
........

java.lang.RuntimeException: no terms in field vendorName - cannot determine sort type
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ExtendedFieldCacheImpl$5.createValue(ExtendedFieldCacheImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl$Cache.get(FieldCacheImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ExtendedFieldCacheImpl.getAuto(ExtendedFieldCacheImpl.java:127)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue.comparatorAuto(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:487)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue$1.createValue(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:184)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl$Cache.get(FieldCacheImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue.getCachedComparator(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:167)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue.(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:55)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldDocCollector.(TopFieldDocCollector.java:43)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:121)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.QueryHits.updateTopDocs(QueryHits.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.QueryHits.(QueryHits.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.FullTextQueryImpl.getQueryHits(FullTextQueryImpl.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:270)
    at com.tis.purchasedetails.dao.PurchaseDetailsDAO.getAllPurchaseDetails(PurchaseDetailsDAO.java:1025)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.PurchaseDetails.purchaseDetailsList_jsp._jspService(purchaseDetailsList_jsp.java:275)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:398)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a different *SortField* constructor. Use the one where you specify also the *type*. See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1729